# Ruby: Dynamically calling available methods raising undefined method (metaprogramming)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, metaprogramming

I have an Activerecord object called `Foo`:

```
Foo.attribute_names.each do |attribute|
  puts Foo.find(:all)[0].method(attribute.to_sym).call
end
```

Here I'm calling all attributes on this model (ie, querying for each column value).
However, sometimes, I'll get an undefined method error.

How can ActiveRecord::Base#attribute_names return an attribute name that when converted into its own method call, raises an undefined method error?

Keep in mind this only happens on certain objects for only certain methods. I can't identify a pattern.

Thank you.

Comment: I can't tell from the code you posted, but you might want to look at what the failing `attribute.to_sym` is. Also, you probably know this already, but `Foo.find(:all)[0]` is horribly inefficient- use `Foo.first` instead.

Comment: attribute.to_sym converts an attribute name that is a String (eg, 'author' to a symbol ':author'. Symbols are the data-type accepted by the Object#method function. This works in principle as only some of the methods are undefined.

Also, I know the db query is terrible, it's not what I'm actually using, it's just easier for everyone else to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NoMethodError should be telling you which method does not exist for what object. Is it possible that your `find` returns no record? In that case, `[][0]` is `nil` and you will get a `NoMethodError` for sure.

I would use `.fetch(0)` instead of `[0]`, and you will get a `KeyError` if ever there is no element with index 0.

Note: no need for `to_sym`; all builtin methods accept name methods as strings or symbols (both in 1.8 and 1.9)

Comment: Don't worry about the query, it's not returning a nil result. And thanks for the .to_sym tip.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something to do with access? Like if a class has an `attr_protected` attribute, or something along that line. Or for attributes that are not database columns, which have no accessors defined?

Comment: All of the attributes that tripped the error were database columns.